# How to allow/deny routes according the "dev/prod" environment in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, access-control

I am using Symfony 4.1.
I am trying to allow/deny a route according the "dev"/"prod" environment.

I tried to define distinct `security` configuration files per environment but I am not allow. The following message is displayed loading the Symfony cache : 
`Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one configuration section.`

Here my security section :

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: '^/$' , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: '^/ping$' , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: '^/docs\.json$' , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I want to allow (without authentication) the `docs.json` route in `dev` environment and restrict (with authentication) the `docs.json` route in `prod` environment.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

With the Symfony ExpressionLanguage component, you can try to add `condition: "'%kernel.environment%' === 'dev'"` In annotations or whatever you are using to define your route.

Comment: As the route is auto-generated via a bundle, I don't have any control on the route configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**The `security.firewalls.dev:` configuration is used in every Symfony environment (dev,test,prod)!**

In Symfony 4, to achieve making some routes available in just some environments, you could do something like this:

**Setup:**

`config/packages/security.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN if the env var is not set.
    env(SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN): '^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/'

security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: '%env(SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN)%'
            security: false
```

**Override per Symfony environment:**

create a new file `config/packages/dev/parameters.yaml`:

```
parameters:
    env(SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN): '^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/|^/docs'
```

Now `/docs` is only available without firewall in the Symfony dev environment

**Override using environment variables:**

You could also override `SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN` in the `.env` file:

`SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN=^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/|^/docs`

This only works if you don't include the `.env` in your production environment, or if you specifically override the `SECURITY_DEV_PATTERN` environment variable there as well.

Answer (score -1):

So I solve the issue by setting-up the `dev` firewall and updating the pattern to bypass the security.

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: '^/$' , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: '^/ping$' , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: '^/docs\.json$' , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: '^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js|docs)/'
            security: false
```

Comment: But just because the firewall is called "dev" doesn't mean it's only active in dev environment, right?